# What is the usage of Client scope and Arguments Scope in ColdFusion Component?

Tags: coldfusion, scope, argument-passing, cfc

Actually i used UserId with Client scope.

Can i use the Client scope directly in a component file or only using via the arguments scope?
Given the following code Which one is right? or Both are right?

Using Client Scope:

```
<cfset getUsers = Application.Users.getAllUsers()>

<cffunction name="getAllUsers" returntype="query">
    <cfquery name="read" datasource="myDsn">
        Select * 
        from Users
        Where UserID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Client.UserID#">
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn read>
</cffunction>
```

Using Argument Scope:

```
<cfset getUsers = Application.Users.getAllUsers(UserID = Client.UserID)>

<cffunction name="getAllUsers" returntype="query">
    <cfargument name="UserID" type="any" required= "true">

    <cfquery name="read" datasource="myDsn">
        Select * 
        from Users
        Where UserID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.UserID#">
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn read>
</cffunction>
```

Please give me the convenient solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you `var` your `read` variable in that function, whichever way you go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When we talk about components, we talk about OOPs and its concepts. When we talk about OOPs, we also talk about encapsulation. Though your first method will work, it breaks encapsulation. Object methods should be oblivious of outside world. Hence, the 2nd method is the right approach. Sometime there are some challenges, where you are needed to take approach in first method, but that is case by case method and specific situations.

Comment: Thanks a lot CFML_Developer

Answer (score 6):

@CFML_Developer has given a good answer. To build on that a bit...

OO theory has a sound basis in reality here (like it usually does, that said). Breaking encapsulation and burrowing out into a function's calling context for its "inputs" pretty much locks the function into being used in that one context. Your function *requires* that client variable to exist, which means it's no bloody good to be used in a situation in which the client variable doesn't exist: it'll just break.

If you write your functions as encapsulated units, then you will "know" that the function will work, provided the code that calls it passes the correct values. It's - rightly - up to the calling code to make sure those values exist.

This works both ways, too: a function should not mess with any information in the calling context: it should only return one value (or poss no value), and it's up to the calling code what's done with that value: the function should not dictate that. Occasionally a function might manipulate data when it's passed-in as a reference (for example most of CFML's array and struct functions), but that should be well documented. And even then: it's the calling code that decides *which* reference to use when calling the function.

Answer (score -5):

Both methods are correct.
You can use the Client scope directly in a component file as well as via the arguments scope.
You can use both methods.
Which one you choose, depends on your requirement.
The second one is preferable.

Comment: That's such a wishy-washy answer that there was almost no point in posting it. The OP was asking about best practices, not what was *possible*.